# React Bootstrap - id not rendered in InputGroup.Text

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to React.

I am using Bootstrap to render my page. All the other tags seem to be working apart from the `InputGroup.Text`. It doesn't render the `id` attribute of the text field. It looks as below if I inspect the element:

```
<input placeholder="Type your question here" class="form-control">
```

I have tried directly entering "1" as the id and that doesn't render either.

```
<InputGroup size="sm" className="mb-3">
  <InputGroup.Prepend>
    <InputGroup.Text id={ans.answerno}>{this.mapAlpha(ans.answerno)}</InputGroup.Text>
  </InputGroup.Prepend>
  <FormControl placeholder="Type your answer here" />
  <Form.Check type="checkbox" id={ans.answerno} label="mark answer" />
</InputGroup>
```

I have checked the documentation online and this seems to me how it should work. Can anyone advise?

Comment: its not showing anything or just not showing "id" ?. id is not meant for showing in ui

Comment: Looks like you're adding id to `InputGroup.Text` and inspecting the `FormControl`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `id` is located inside a `span` before the `<input>`.

[image]

Even checking the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/input-group/) rendered code

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this. How would it work though if I have an on onChange event handler attached to the input?

Comment: That's up to the API. You'll have to dig the source code, but there seems to be a base components and its [`props`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/InputGroup.js#L41)

Comment: Okay, got it, I need to add the id attribute to the FormControl and the onChange event handler to that element as well.

Comment: I think you should take a look at the docs, looks like `onChange` belongs to [`Form.Control`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/forms/#form-control-props). [InputGroup](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/input-group/) looks more visual than interactive.